# Adding Views Programatically in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view, scrollview, layout-inflater

I've followed some previous questions and I've even solved this issue in some other projects, but for some reason I can't solve it here.

I have an app which creates "tasks" and creates a countdown for each one.

I have a view model with a list, and its observable via LiveData

```
  val tasksList = mutableListOf<Task>()

    private val _tasksListData = MutableLiveData(tasksList)
    val tasksListData : LiveData<MutableList<Task>>
        get() = _tasksListData

    fun addNewTask(task : Task){
        tasksList.add(task)
        _tasksListData.value = tasksList
    }
```

I have already check that the items are created via a log statement. So that's working alright.

Then in the fragment I'm observing this live data and trying to add dynamically each tag, but for some reason these are not shown:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_history,
            container,
            false
        )

        taskListContainer = binding.tasksListContainer

        tasksViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(TasksViewModel::class.java)


        //Checks if the list has some items, otherwise displays a message
        checkTasksList()

        tasksViewModel.tasksListData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
            for (item in it) {

                val view: IndividualTaskViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    inflater, R.layout.individual_task_view, container, false
                )

                view.taskTitle.text = item.name
                view.taskDateCreated.text = item.dateCreated
                view.taskTertiaryText.text = item.cyclesCompleted.toString()

                taskListContainer.addView(view.root)
            }

            checkTasksList()
        })

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun checkTasksList(){
        if(taskListContainer.childCount == 0 ){
            binding.emptyListText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        } else{
            binding.emptyListText.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the layout for each individual task:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:minHeight="88dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/task_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tomato" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/task_item_icon"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_date_created"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/task_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/task_item_icon"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Date created"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_tertiary_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/task_date_created"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/task_item_icon"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="task_tertiary_text"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And here's the layour of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".FragmentHistory">

<!-- using constraint layout so I can have the views floating in the screen-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_list_text"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/list_empty_text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tasks_list_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

As I mentioned before, the tasks are added to the list correclty, and the LiveData is also updated everytime a new task is added. But then the observer is not working, or the problem is when the layout is inflated.

Thank you very much for your help.

The entire project is here: https://github.com/arieldipietro/PomodoroTechnique

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for this list? It'd work really nicely with what it sounds like you're trying to do.

Comment: Just because it's highly unlikely that the users would have a large number of items to display. And since it's just for practice, I didn't think it'd be that necessary..

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the problem is with the observer so I'm posting a new question [Adding an Observer in a Tabbed Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919073/adding-an-observer-in-a-tabbed-activity)