# Adding an Observer in a Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, observers

I have an app which creates "tasks" and creates a countdown for each one.

I have a view model with a list, and it's observable via `LiveData`

```
val tasksList = mutableListOf<Task>()

private val _tasksListData = MutableLiveData(tasksList)
val tasksListData : LiveData<MutableList<Task>>
    get() = _tasksListData

fun addNewTask(task : Task){
    tasksList.add(task)
    _tasksListData.value = tasksList
}
```

I have already check that the items are created via a log statement. So that's working alright.

Then in the fragment I'm observing this live data and trying to add dynamically each task.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_history,
            container,
            false
        )

        taskListContainer = binding.tasksListContainer

        tasksViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(TasksViewModel::class.java)


        //Checks if the list has some items, otherwise displays a message
        checkTasksList()

        tasksViewModel.tasksListData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
            for (item in it) {

                val view: IndividualTaskViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    inflater, R.layout.individual_task_view, container, false
                )

                view.taskTitle.text = item.name
                view.taskDateCreated.text = item.dateCreated
                view.taskTertiaryText.text = item.cyclesCompleted.toString()

                taskListContainer.addView(view.root)
            }

            checkTasksList()
        })

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun checkTasksList(){
        if(taskListContainer.childCount == 0 ){
            binding.emptyListText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        } else{
            binding.emptyListText.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that `onCreateView()` is called just once, and then I can't find a way to Observe the `LiveData` again. I have checked with Log statements, but while I'm swapping tabs (meaning I'm swapping fragments), I can't get any method from the Fragment's lifecycle.

The entire project is here: https://github.com/arieldipietro/PomodoroTechnique

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the deprecated [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) instead of [Migrating to ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) which *does* change your fragment's lifecycle based on what tab you are on?

Comment: No, actually I just used the template provided by Android Studio. You think that should solve the problem?